# Unable to do simple insert with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to copy data from a table in Sybase server into the same table in Oracle server (Oracle 11g).
I thought it would be easier to do it using my coldfusion web programming because the 2 different db server.
Unfortunately, I got the following error from Oracle. I don't think my syntax is wrong. because all the comma are there and no missing comma as the error says. I think it may be due to the DATE column that's set as DATE datatype.

Here is the error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.  
[Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-00917: missing comma
```

The error occurred in `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test.cfm: line 65`

```
63 :      #um_gs_dnrcnt_cfm_pp#,                                           
64 :      #um_gs_amt_cfm_pg_pp#,                                            
65 :      #um_gs_dnrcnt_cfm_pg_pp#)
66 :     </cfquery>
67 : </cfoutput>



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQLSTATE   HY000 
SQL    INSERT INTO um_gift_sum (um_gs_fyr, um_gs_inst, um_gs_dept, 
                                um_gs_dt_of_record, um_gs_fund_type, 
                                um_gs_dnr_type,
                                um_gs_amt_cash, um_gs_dnrcnt_cash, um_gs_amt_pl,
                                um_gs_dnrcnt_pl, um_gs_amt_pp, um_gs_dnrcnt_pp,  
                                um_gs_amt_pp_prior, um_gs_dnrcnt_pp_prior, 
                                um_gs_amt_gik, um_gs_dnrcnt_gik, 
                                um_gs_amt_pg_cash, 
                                um_gs_dnrcnt_pg_cash, um_gs_amt_pg_pl, 
                                um_gs_dnrcnt_pg_pl, um_gs_amt_pg_pp, 
                                um_gs_dnrcnt_pg_pp, um_gs_amt_gft_mtch, 
                                um_gs_dnrcnt_gft_mtch, um_gs_amt_cfm_pp, 
                                um_gs_dnrcnt_cfm_pp, um_gs_amt_cfm_pg_pp,  
                                um_gs_dnrcnt_cfm_pg_pp) 
       VALUES('1995', 'AB', 'MAA', 1995-01-31 00:00:00.0, '1', 'FR', 100.0000, 0,
              0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 
              0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0)
```

### Here is my insert statement:

```
<cfquery name="x" datasource="SybaseDB">                   
 SELECT TOP 10 * FROM um_sum                               
</cfquery>                                                 

<cfoutput query="x">                                       

  <cfquery name="Y" datasource="OracleDB">                 
  INSERT INTO um_sum (um_gs_fyr,                           
                 m_gs_inst,                                  
                      um_gs_dept,                          
                      um_gs_dt_of_record,                  
                      um_gs_fund_type,                     
            um_gs_dnr_type,                                     

            etc,                                                 

            um_gs_dnrcnt_cfm_pp,                              
            um_gs_amt_cfm_pg_pp,                              
                 um_gs_dnrcnt_cfm_pg_pp)                    
    VALUES('#um_gs_fyr#',                                    
                '#um_gs_inst#',                                 
                '#um_gs_dept#',                                 
    #um_gs_dt_of_record#,    <---- this is date datatype, 
                                   I suspect this may be the problem?          
                '#um_gs_fund_type#',                            
                '#um_gs_dnr_type#',                             
    #um_gs_amt_cash#,                                        
                    #um_gs_dnrcnt_cash#,                         
                    #um_gs_amt_pl#,                              
                    #um_gs_dnrcnt_pl#,                           
                    #um_gs_amt_pp#,                              
                    #um_gs_dnrcnt_pp#,                           
                    #um_gs_amt_pp_prior#,                        
                    #um_gs_dnrcnt_pp_prior#,                     
                    #um_gs_amt_gik#,                             
                    #um_gs_dnrcnt_gik#,                          
                    #um_gs_amt_pg_cash#,                         
                    #um_gs_dnrcnt_pg_cash#,                      
                    #um_gs_amt_pg_pl#,                           
                    #um_gs_dnrcnt_pg_pl#,                        
                    #um_gs_amt_pg_pp#,                           
                    #um_gs_dnrcnt_pg_pp#,                        
                    #um_gs_amt_gft_mtch#,                        
                    #um_gs_dnrcnt_gft_mtch#,                     

         #um_gs_amt_cfm_pp#,                               

         #um_gs_dnrcnt_cfm_pp#,                            
                    #um_gs_amt_cfm_pg_pp#,                       
    #um_gs_dnrcnt_cfm_pg_pp#)                                
    </cfquery>                                             
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: What's up with this #...# notation?

Comment: @Olaf, the #...# is the coldfusion part

Comment: This looks awfully open to SQL injection

Answer (score 3):

this part is not surrounded with single quotes properly.

```
AA', 1995-01-31 00:00:00.0, '1'
```

**edit (based on comment)**
if the single quotes don't fix it, then you could explicitly declare the date format in a `to_date()` function

Comment: I would highly recommend using TO_DATE with the correct date definition string.